# iOS App - Vietnamese localization

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, app-store-connect, southeast-asian-languages

I'm trying to localize my app to vietnamese; on iTunes Connect there is a Vietnamese localization but in Xcode there is two versions: Vietnamese (vi) and Vietnamese (Vietnam) (vi_VN). I received the translations from english with no more information that it's vietnamese. Is there someone who already localized an app to vietnamese and can advice me what should i choose ?

Comment: I did it before. What I did is just create 2 localized string file, one for vi and one for vi_VN. The content of the 2 files are the same. I'm a Vietnamese and not event sure what is the different between these 2, so just make it the same to be sure. It is not that hard to keep the content of the 2 files the same.